# Codeigniter - how to remove the index.php from url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following structure of my project

```
/system
/applications
  /cache
  /core
  /helpers
  /hook
  /language
  /libraries
  /logs
  /third_party
  /admin-panel
     /config
     /controllers
        welcome.php
        dashboard.php
     /errors
     /models
     /views
        welcome.php
        dashboard.php
  /user-panel
     /config
     /controllers
            welcome.php
            dashboard.php
     /errors
     /models
     /views
        welcome.php
        dashboard.php
/admin
  index.php
index.php
```

My index.php inside my project folder has user-panel as my application folder and index.php in admin folder has admin-panel as my application folder.

I have inserted this line
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['welcome'] = 'welcome';
in routes.php inside both user-panel and admin-panel

I can access welcome controller of my both user-panel and admin-panel by using `http://localhost/myproject and http://localhost/myproject/admin`

but i cannot access my dashboard controller by using `http://localhost/myproject/dashboard or http://localhost/myproject/admin/dashboard`

my dashboard controller is accessible by using `http://localhost/myproject/index.php/dashboard or http://localhost/myproject/admin/index.php/dashboard`

But i dont want index.php included in my url. I want to remove it. I have also tried by using .htaccess inside my admin folder. I write following line in this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

but this didn't work for me. It give 404 not found CI error. I have also enabled mod_rewrite by changing AllowOerride None to AllowOverride All in httpd.conf. Please tell me what should i do to remove index.php and where  should i place my .htaccess files in my project directory.

Comment: are you sure the rewrite module is loaded in Apache.

Comment: As i have said that i have changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All and my .htaccess is in my admin folder. Is this a correct location?

Comment: try placing your .htaccess in project's root folder

Comment: locate it in the same directory with index.php

Comment: should i create two .htaccess files in both my project folder and admin folder because i index.php in both location?

Comment: Only one, the one you added above, just remove it to be in the same directory with index.php

Answer (score 10):

if your root folder for project is not root of domain i.e. your website is subdirectory of a domain `http://localhost/myproject` then you need an additional line in your .htaccess file that is `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also make sure, your config.php is configured as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And mod_rewrite is enable in apache's config file.

Answer (score 2):

Open config.php from system/application/config directory

and replace

$config['index_page'] = “index.php” by $config['index_page'] = “”

Create a “.htaccess” file in the root of CodeIgniter directory

and add the following lines.

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In some case the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly.

To solve this problem just replace

```
`$config['uri_protocol'] = “AUTO”`
```

by

```
 $config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI”
```

from system/application/config/config.php

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of the following :

1. .htaccess needs to be placed in the same directory as the index.php file, usually root of the application.
2. [read the manual about codeigniter and .htaccess](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)
3. Be sure that apache is running the rewrite module named : **rewrite_module** you can read more about enabling the module on linux here : [Blog post](http://www.lavluda.com/2007/07/15/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache22-debian/) or for wamp here : Wamp icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules -> **rewrite_module**

Comment: Can you tell me what should i write in .htaccess?

Comment: yes.  I wrote these lines in my .htaccess as given in your url

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: I have also enabled my mod_rewrite module

Comment: did you restart the server, so rewrite module will become active ?

Comment: but when i save my .htaccess files inside my project then i cant access my homee page by using http://localhost/myproject

Comment: instead i get wamp screen having a list of project in my www direcotory.

Comment: Please look my project structure is this correct according to codeigniter.

Comment: you should watch this codeigniter video : http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/ ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the config.php file, there is a variable named `'index_page'`

try changing

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Comment: my application folder is not inside system folder and also my config folder is in my user-panel folder and admin-panel folder.

Comment: try to change $config['index_page'] = "index.php"; value in config.php file to blank value $config['index_page'] = " "; and also .htaccess that you already done !